# Segmentation Fault using fscanf in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read names from a text file in my code for .c, but I keep getting a segmentation fault from fscanf and can't seem to find out what the problem is.

I tried multiple options, including increasing the char array size, but I have no idea what is wrong, any help would be appreciated.

I also executed this in the DevC++ and it worked, but when I used gcc, it gave me that segfault error.

in main

```c
FILE* infile;
char buffer[20];
```

in a switch case in main

```c
infile = fopen("pathway", "r");
for (i=-1; i < name; i++)
{
     fscanf(infile, "%s", buffer);
}
fclose(infile);
```

the file

```
Zeda'Taxu
Khano'Balme
Goni
...
...
```

Comment: did you check if `infile==NULL`?

Comment: What do you think happens if the file "pathway" does not exist in the current directory?

Comment: i checked an infile != NULL

Comment: I think you should be using a while loop instead, to make sure you are reading while there is something in the file. What if there are less words than the number of iterations in your case?

Comment: I doublechecked the pathway and it exists

Comment: then a `"%19s"` making sure that you do not exceed the buffer size might solve your problem. Anyway, it seems as reading lines through `fgets` might be more apropriate.

Comment: I tried the %19s and that doesnt work for me. There are 100 words in the text doc and name int ranges from 0-99 so I do not think that would be it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. The problem may be elsewhere in your code. _"I checked an infile != NULL"_: well the code you show in your question doesn't.

Comment: What else are you doing with `i`? The loop is unusual, would expect `for (i=0; i <= name; i++)` or even `for (i=0; i < name; i++)` if `name == 100`.

Comment: what happens if there are less than `name` words in the file?

Comment: I put i as -1 to access the 0th line of the text file. Name is a random integer between 0-99, so i dont think  `name` would be smaller than the amount of words in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of points to be made (1) *never skimp on buffer size*. `20` is horribly insufficient for a large percentage of names in use. `64` may be a reasonable size, and then you take that reasonable size and *double* it.

Next, (2) it is unclear what `name` does in your code, but since it is used in a `for` loop limit, that seems to be the number of names you wish to limit your read to. You must control your read loop so it exits when 1 - your read index is no longer less than your `name` limit `&&` fgets() returns a valid pointer, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 128   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NUMNM  10   /*        ( Don't skimp on buffer size! )        */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buffer[MAXNM];
    size_t ndx = 0, name = NUMNM;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    ...
    while (ndx < name && fgets (buffer, MAXNM, fp)) {
        buffer[strcspn (buffer, "\n")] = 0; /* overwrite \n with nul-char */
        fprintf (stdout, "name[%2zu] : %s\n", ndx++ + 1, buffer);
    }
```

Above a simple `ndx` (index) variable is used along with the return from `fgets` to control your read loop. This eliminates your problem of having less lines than `names` in the file, but then blindly pushing ahead reading from a stream in error-state until `name` iterations take place. By using `ndx < NUMNM && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)` as the loop control, you gracefully exit when either condition in no longer true avoiding *Undefined Behavior*.

(3) if you intend to store the name from each `buffer`, you then need to allocate storage for each name and copy `buffer` to the new storage before your next iteration or the prior name will be lost when `buffer` is refilled.

(4) `fgets` reads up to, and includes, the trailing `'\n'` at the end of the buffer filled. You do not want to store your names with `'\n'`s dangling off the end. `strcspn` is one of the simplest and most robust ways of determining the number of characters in `buffer` before the `'\n'` and then simply overwriting the `'\n'` with the *nul-character*. You need nothing more than was shown above, e.g.

```
        buffer[strcspn (buffer, "\n")] = 0; /* overwrite \n with nul-char */
```

Refer to [strspn(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) and see if you can figure out exactly how that works.

(5) *Always* check the return of *every* file opening (and closing after the stream has been written to), and *always* check the return of *every* user-input function. There is no more critical step in your code than validating the data you receive from a file or a user *Before* you attempt to process that data. Otherwise you are just inviting *Undefined Behavior* with as little as the slip of a keystroke, or a single misspelling.

Putting it altogether in a program that takes the filename to open as the first argument to the program (or reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided), you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 128   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NUMNM  10   /*        ( Don't skimp on buffer size! )        */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buffer[MAXNM];
    size_t ndx = 0, name = NUMNM;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (ndx < name && fgets (buffer, MAXNM, fp)) {
        buffer[strcspn (buffer, "\n")] = 0; /* overwrite \n with nul-char */
        fprintf (stdout, "name[%2zu] : %s\n", ndx++ + 1, buffer);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Input File**

Now exercise your input routine with a file containing 11 names, one more than NUMNM allows to be read, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/namesonly.txt
Zeda'Taxu
Khano'Balme
Goni
Ryan,Elizabeth
McIntyre,Osborne
DuMond,Kristin
Larson,Lois
Thorpe,Trinity
Ruiz,Pedro
Ali,Mohammed
Vashti,Indura
```

**Example Use/Output**

Reading and stopping a NUMNM names

```
$ ./bin/fgetsnames <dat/namesonly.txt
name[ 1] : Zeda'Taxu
name[ 2] : Khano'Balme
name[ 3] : Goni
name[ 4] : Ryan,Elizabeth
name[ 5] : McIntyre,Osborne
name[ 6] : DuMond,Kristin
name[ 7] : Larson,Lois
name[ 8] : Thorpe,Trinity
name[ 9] : Ruiz,Pedro
name[10] : Ali,Mohammed
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons which could lead to undefined behaviour.

First, a possible `NULL` in `infile`; Second, exceeding the buffer size in one of the lines of the file. In order not to change to much of your logic, a quick fix could be:

```
FILE* infile;
char buffer[20];
infile = fopen("pathway", "r");
if (infile!=NULL) {
  for (i=-1; i < name; i++) {
     fscanf(infile, "19%s", buffer);
  }
}
```

You might consider using `fgets` instead. Confer, for example, the following example copied from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm):

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main () {
>    FILE *fp;
>    char str[60];
>
>    /* opening file for reading */
>    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
>    if(fp == NULL) {
>       perror("Error opening file");
>       return(-1);
>    }
>    if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
>       /* writing content to stdout */
>       puts(str);
>    }
>    fclose(fp);
>
>    return(0);
> }
> ```

Comment: By exceeding the buffer size, do you mean that one of the names in the text file is larger than the char array size?

Comment: yes, more than 19 characters would exceed the buffer, since you need one additional byte for the string termination character.

Comment: What about the `'\n'` now dangling off each surname? Maybe a quick `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;`?